# Testing file upload with Flask and Python 3

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, flask

I'm using Flask with Python 3.3 and I know support is still experimental but I'm running into errors when trying to test file uploads. I'm using `unittest.TestCase` and based on Python 2.7 examples I've seen in the docs I'm trying

```
rv = self.app.post('/add', data=dict(
                               file=(io.StringIO("this is a test"), 'test.pdf'),
                           ), follow_redirects=True)
```

and getting

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I've tried a few variations around io.StringIO but can't find anything that works.  Any help is much appreciated!

The full stack trace is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "archive_tests.py", line 44, in test_add_transcript
    ), follow_redirects=True)
  File "/srv/transcript_archive/py3env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 771, in post
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
  File "/srv/transcript_archive/py3env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/flask/testing.py", line 108, in open
    follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File "/srv/transcript_archive/py3env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 725, in open
    environ = args[0].get_environ()
  File "/srv/transcript_archive/py3env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 535, in get_environ
    stream_encode_multipart(values, charset=self.charset)
  File "/srv/transcript_archive/py3env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 98, in stream_encode_multipart
    write_binary(chunk)
  File "/srv/transcript_archive/py3env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 59, in write_binary
    stream.write(string)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Comment: What is the full traceback? Why are you using `io.StringIO()` to post, could it be that you need a binary file object here? `io.BytesIO(b'this is a test')` might work, for example.

Comment: Looking at the [`werkzeug` `FileStorage` object](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/datastructures.py) (which handles file uploads in a test) I don't see anything that'll give me enough information. You'll need to add the **full** traceback for anyone to be able to say anything useful.

Comment: Sorry, added the trace.  I'm using `io.String` because the werkzeug examples use `StringIO` in their examples [link](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/test/).  Using `io.BytesIO` made no difference.

Comment: `StringIO` in Python 2 handles *byte strings*, not Unicode. The Python 3 equivalent is `io.BytesIO`.

Comment: OK, `file=(io.BytesIO(b"this is a test"), 'test.pdf')` does work, I had forgotten to put the `b` in front of the quoted text when I tested after your initial response. Thanks!

Comment: I was *just* busy typing in an incredulous response; reading the `werkzeug.test` module made it clear it is writing the files over to a `BytesIO` object, so it'll expect a binary file object.

Comment: I've typed this up as an answer below, for future visitors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Python 3, you need to use `io.BytesIO()` (with a bytes value) to simulate an uploaded file:

```
rv = self.app.post('/add', data=dict(
                               file=(io.BytesIO(b"this is a test"), 'test.pdf'),
                           ), follow_redirects=True)
```

Note the `b'...'` string defining a `bytes` literal.

In the Python 2 test examples, the `StringIO()` object holds a byte string, not a `unicode` value, and in Python 3, `io.BytesIO()` is the equivalent.

Comment: If, instead of BytesIO, you are using an actual file, remember to open it in binary mode with ``open('filename.data', 'rb')``