# Testing file uploads in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm using [Flask-Testing](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/) for my Flask integration tests. I've got a form that has a file upload for a logo that I'm trying to write tests for but I keep getting an error saying: `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`.

I'm using Python 3. The closest answer I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080123/testing-file-upload-with-flask-and-python-3) but it's not working for me.

This is what one of my many attempts looks like:

```
def test_edit_logo(self):
    """Test can upload logo."""
    data = {'name': 'this is a name', 'age': 12}
    data['file'] = (io.BytesIO(b"abcdef"), 'test.jpg')
    self.login()
    response = self.client.post(
        url_for('items.save'), data=data, follow_redirects=True)
    })
    self.assertIn(b'Your item has been saved.', response.data)
    advert = Advert.query.get(1)
    self.assertIsNotNone(item.logo)
```

How does one test a file upload in Flask?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The issue ended up not being that when one adds `content_type='multipart/form-data'` to the `post` method it expect all values in `data` to either be files or strings. There were integers in my data dict which I realised thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684436/testing-file-uploads-in-flask/35707921?noredirect=1#comment59099614_35707921) comment.

So the end solution ended up looking like this:

```
def test_edit_logo(self):
    """Test can upload logo."""
    data = {'name': 'this is a name', 'age': 12}
    data = {key: str(value) for key, value in data.items()}
    data['file'] = (io.BytesIO(b"abcdef"), 'test.jpg')
    self.login()
    response = self.client.post(
        url_for('adverts.save'), data=data, follow_redirects=True,
        content_type='multipart/form-data'
    )
    self.assertIn(b'Your item has been saved.', response.data)
    advert = Item.query.get(1)
    self.assertIsNotNone(item.logo)
```

Comment: I love you so much I would kiss you right now. I wasted a whole hour trying to figure out what was wrong...good sir, you are my savior.

Comment: Is `files` a special key for the `data` parameter, or is that actually passed to the API. If so, what's the point of the file name?

Comment: Just to demystify this a bit, the values in the "file-like-tuple" assigned to `data['file']` are converted into arguments of [werkzeug.datastructures.FileMultiDict.add_file](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileMultiDict), so it can take an optional third value specifying the file's `content_type` (different from the content_type of the whole request)

Answer (score 27):

You need two things:

1.)  `content_type='multipart/form-data'` in your `.post()`
2.)  in your `data=` pass in `file=(BytesIO(b'my file contents'), "file_name.jpg")`

A full example:

```
    data = dict(
        file=(BytesIO(b'my file contents'), "work_order.123"),
    )

    response = app.post(url_for('items.save'), content_type='multipart/form-data', data=data)
```

Comment: Thanks @mam8cc. Can you clarify point 2 for me? It sounds to me like you're saying pass a keyword argument to a dictionary which I don't think is what you mean. Can you give me a short code example?

Comment: @hammygoonan I've updated the question with a more complete example.

Comment: Thanks again @mam8cc, I think we're getting somewhere. If I use the code you've got in your answer then it fixes the issue. However when I add additional fields to the data dict it breaks with the `TypeError`. I've edited my question to make that clearer.

Comment: @hammygoonan I recall running into your issue.  Try ensuring that all your values you pass along with it are wrapped in quotes.  The comments in our codebase where we do this type of testing implies its required (as to why I cannot tell you).  

`data = dict(miles="1", file=(BytesIO(b'my file contents'), "work_order.pdf"))`

Comment: If you have the file on your filesystem you need to do `with open(path_to_file, 'rb') as f: data['file'] = (f, f.name)`

Answer (score 20):

You can use Werkzeug's `FileStorage` (as used by Flask under the hood) which you don't need to install as it comes with Flask.

You can mock a file like this:

```
import io
import json

from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage

# Here we are mocking a JSON file called Input.json
my_dict = {"msg": "hello!"}
input_json = json.dumps(my_dict, indent=4).encode("utf-8")

mock_file = FileStorage(
    stream=io.BytesIO(input_json),
    filename="Input.json",
    content_type="application/json",
)
```

This example uses a real file to test against:

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage


my_file = FileStorage(
    stream=open("tests/assets/my_video.mp4", "rb"),
    filename="my_video.mp4",
    content_type="video/mpeg",
)

rv = client.post(
   "/api/v1/video",
   data={
      "my_video": my_file,
   },
   content_type="multipart/form-data"
)
```

Test to see it returns a response status code of 200:

```
assert "200" in rv.status
```

I can then test that the file arrives in a test directory on the server:

```
assert "my_video.mp4" in os.listdir("tests/my_test_path")
```

Also note, you need to set the mocked file to `None` on teardown otherwise you'll get a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` . Below is a Pytest example:

```
    def setup_method(self):
        self.mock_file = FileStorage(
            stream=io.BytesIO(input_json),
            filename="Input.json",
            content_type="application/json",
        )

    def teardown_method(self):
        self.mock_file = None
```

Comment: This works for me, whereas the accepted answer does not.

Comment: Thanks for the code which uses a real file to upload instead of byte stream.

Answer (score 4):

While trying to find a bug in my code I've created a SSCCE for file upload (based on [the docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/)) with a corresponding test based on other answers here. It might be useful for somebody:

app.py:

```
import base64
import os
import pathlib
import tempfile
import textwrap

import flask
import werkzeug.utils

root = flask.Blueprint('root', __name__)

@root.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            file = flask.request.files['file']
            if not file.filename:
                raise LookupError()
            filename = werkzeug.utils.secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(pathlib.Path(flask.current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            flask.flash('File saved!', 'message')
        except LookupError:
            flask.flash('No file provided!', 'error')
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('root.upload_file'))
    else:
        return flask.render_template_string(textwrap.dedent(
            '''\
            <!doctype html>
            <title>Upload new File</title>
            {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}{% if messages %}
            <ul class=flashes>
            {% for category, message in messages %}<li class="{{ category }}">{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}{% endwith %}
            <h1>Upload new File</h1>
            <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
            <input type=file name=file>
            <input type=submit value=Upload>
            </form>
            '''
        ))

def create_app():
    app = flask.Flask(__name__)
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = tempfile.gettempdir()
    app.secret_key = 'change-me'
    app.register_blueprint(root)
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_app()
```

test_app.py:

```
"""upload tests"""

import base64
import io
import unittest

import werkzeug

import app

# https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mathiasbynens/small/master/jpeg.jpg
SMALLEST_JPEG_B64 = """\
/9j/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8Q
EBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/yQALCAABAAEBAREA/8wABgAQEAX/2gAIAQEAAD8A0s8g/9k=
"""

class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_save(self):
        with app.create_app().test_client() as client:
            file = werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage(
                stream=io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(SMALLEST_JPEG_B64)),
                filename="example image.jpg",
                content_type="image/jpg",
            )
            response = client.post(
                '/',
                data=dict(
                    file=file,
                ),
                follow_redirects=True,
                content_type='multipart/form-data',
            )
```