# flask unittest for the following function no response

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have written a flask upload function to predict images of uploaded images. It is predicting as expected but the unitest block is missing the from `request.files.getlist` to return. The code and unittest block

code:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if "images" not in request.files:
            return render_template('index.html'), 201
        files1 = request.files.getlist("images")
        results = {}
        rmodel = tf.keras.models.load_model(MODEL)
        for file in files1:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            image = Image.open(file)
            demo = np.array(image)
            demo = demo[:, :, ::-1].copy()
            demo = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(demo, tf.float32)
            demo = tf.image.resize(demo, size=[300, 300])
            demo = np.expand_dims(demo, axis=0)
            pred = r.predict(demo)
            result = np.argmax(pred)
            results[filename] = RClASSES[result]
        return render_template("results.html", heading=HEADINGLIST, result=results), 201
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Unittest blocK:

```
def test_upload_1files(test_client):

image = "fakeimage1.png"
data = {
    'image': (open(image, 'rb'), image),
    'filename': image
}
rv = test_client.post('/', data=data, content_type='multipart/form-data')

assert rv.status_code == 201
assert image == rv.json["filename"]
```

FAILED test/test_app.py::test_upload_1files - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

no response on the uploaded image for the unitestblock

Thanks in advance

Comment: on which line is the error?

Comment: The text says unittest but it's tagged pytest. Those are different libraries. Which is it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello @SLDem,  eeror for the line assert image== rv.json["filename] and  When i execute the unit test   test_upload_1files(test_client) the image should process through code upload_file function but it does not process through the lines from request.files.getlist("images) to return

Comment: Hello @ggorlen, its pytest library i was unit testing the unittest block  test_upload_1files(test_client) and getting the above error and when i run the code coverage the lines from request.files.getlist("images) to return are misssing

Comment: `test_upload_1files` looks like a pytest function, not a [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) function. I think there's just some language confusion. You're "unit testing" using the pytest library, not the unittest library. I would use "unit test" rather than "unittest" because "unittest" is a specific library unrelated to this question.

Comment: looks like your image isnt uploading correctly because your server cant see any `filename`s in your response object, try looking at this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684436/testing-file-uploads-in-flask

Answer (score 0):

`rv.json` is `None` because `render_template("results.html", heading=HEADINGLIST, result=results), 201` returns HTML (and not JSON).

You'll either have to replace `render_template` with `flask.jsonify()` or look for a value in the returned HTML to verify that the upload succeeded.